# canvas translate path notworking

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a path that I draw well on the canvas.

But I can't move it.

```
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
    const render = () => {
        ctx.resetTransform()
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight)
        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.moveTo(30, 50)
        ctx.lineTo(150, 100)
        ctx.translate(1000,100) // not working
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'red'
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    render()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use path2D and DOMMatrix.

```js
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')

document.body.appendChild(canvas)
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

let pathX = 0
let p1, p2
const render = () => {
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight)

//static path
p1 = new Path2D()
p1.moveTo(30, 50)
p1.lineTo(150, 100)
p2 = new Path2D()
p2.addPath(p1, new DOMMatrix().rotate(-15))
ctx.strokeStyle = 'green'
ctx.stroke(p2)

//dynamic path
p1 = new Path2D()
p1.moveTo(30, 50)
p1.lineTo(150, 100)
p2 = new Path2D()
p2.addPath(p1, new DOMMatrix().translate(pathX++, 0))
ctx.strokeStyle = 'red'
ctx.stroke(p2)

requestAnimationFrame(render)
}
render()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

ctx.resetTransform()
ctx.fillStyle = 'green'

const render = () => {
    ctx.translate(1, 0)
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight)

    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.moveTo(30, 50)
    ctx.lineTo(150, 100)
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'red'
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 64, 36)
}

const interval = 25
let done = 0

const update = () => requestAnimationFrame(time => {
    let dt = time - done

    while (dt > interval) {
        dt -= interval
        done += interval

        render()
    }

    update()
})

update()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="moving-canvas"></canvas>

  <script>
    const canvas = document.querySelector('#moving-canvas')
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```